# Change wallpaper of window

Tags: windows-7

I had nude photos set as wallpaper, now I can’t change it back. Please help.
I do not know how to change it.
I want to remove it.

I don’t have Google so I do not no.

Comment: Please take [the tour](https://superuser.com/tour) and read [how to write a good question](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).  How are we supposed to know what you have already tried?

Comment: Try to right click ANY OTHER PHOTO and choose "set as desktop background".

Answer (score 1):

Search > display > personalization > Backgrounds > set new background/wallpaper

BTW, Google is not something you have, it's something you use.  If you have internet, you have the ability to use Google. You can visit Google here: https://www.google.com/

Also note, that it's possible that some websites are restricted by your country and your internet provider, as [Señor CMasMas](https://superuser.com/users/1000631/se%C3%B1or-cmasmas) mentioned in the comments. You can bypass it by using a [VPN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_private_network).

Comment: `If you have internet you have the ability to use google` .. tell that to the Chinese. .. or the Iranians.. or the Cubans.. or the North Koreans.. or the Syrians.. or the Sudanese.. or the Crimeans..

Comment: We can assume OP is in one of those countries?

Comment: We have no way to know where OP is but I might guess as much.  I think that people know if they can get to google or not.

Comment: Or Bing.. Or other search engines..

Answer (score 0):

Nude background? Lol.

Right click on an image and you should see something along the lines of Set as background image.